# sorting k block array in best time

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures

Suppose we have an array consisting of k blocks. Each block is unsorted, but we have the knowledge that every block is smaller than all the blocks on its right and larger than the blocks on its left. What is the best time complexity we can achieve to sort this array?

is there a way better than O(nlogn) ?

Comment: Note that O(nlogn) is optimal for k=1.  The more general case would be k*O((n/k)*log(n/k)).

Comment: What does it mean that a block is smaller than another?

Comment: Are all the blocks the same size?